# Class Constructor declared twice

Tags: c++, arduino

In the Arduino IDE I am getting an error about how my Constructor is declared twice.

This is the code for it:

tond.h

```
#ifndef TOND_H
#define TOND_H

class Tondeuse {

public:
  Tondeuse();
  Tondeuse(int,int);

};

#endif
```

tond.cpp

```
#ifndef TOND
#define TOND

#include "arduino.h"
#include "tond.h"


Tondeuse::Tondeuse()
{

}

Tondeuse::Tondeuse(int h, int w)
{

Serial.println("Hello");

}



#endif
```

And the errors:

```
Tondeuse.cpp.o: In function `Tondeuse':
/tond.cpp:11: multiple definition of `Tondeuse::Tondeuse()'
tond.cpp.o:C:\Users\DEPANNE\AppData\Local      \Temp\build6942484698459603114.tmp/tond.cpp:11: first defined here
Tondeuse.cpp.o: In function `Tondeuse':
/tond.cpp:11: multiple definition of `Tondeuse::Tondeuse()'
tond.cpp.o:C:\Users\DEPANNE\AppData\Local   \Temp\build6942484698459603114.tmp/tond.cpp:11: first defined here
Tondeuse.cpp.o: In function `Tondeuse':
/tond.cpp:16: multiple definition of `Tondeuse::Tondeuse(int, int)'
tond.cpp.o:C:\Users\DEPANNE\AppData\Local\Temp\build6942484698459603114.tmp/tond.cpp:16: first defined here
Tondeuse.cpp.o: In function `Tondeuse':
/tond.cpp:16: multiple definition of `Tondeuse::Tondeuse(int, int)'
tond.cpp.o:C:\Users\DEPANNE\AppData\Local\Temp\build6942484698459603114.tmp/tond.cpp:16: first defined here
```

I have not included it twice and can't find anything that is wrong with it.

Comment: Well, what's Tondeuse.cpp? Did you forget to remove the object file from it?

Comment: Also, you don't need include guards on cpp files as you never include them.

Comment: @Pubby you sure about that?

Comment: What's in the `Tondeuse.cpp` file?

Comment: Amend that to say "You *SHOULD* never include them".

Comment: @BenVoigt well, not *never*...

Comment: @Luchian: Now that toolchains support link-time optimization, you can do a unity build without ever including a .cpp file into another.  Do you know of another legitimate reason?

Comment: @BenVoigt no, and I've never heard of this. Where can I read some more? (maybe I can get rid of the bulk builds in my code)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zza0de8.aspx

Comment: @BenVoigt isn't that strictly related to optimizing the code, not the actual build time?

Comment: @Luchian: It changes build times considerably also.  (Many people complain about it since you basically have to rebuild everything during the link step so it's the cost of a full build... but a bulk build isn't incremental either)

Comment: From the perspective of build time, if you're willing to sacrifice incremental build for a faster full build, put project headers into the precompiled-header.  The common wisdom of avoiding PCH rebuild doesn't have so much value when using LTO.

Comment: @BenVoigt not all platforms support pch's.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Not all, but it's pretty close.  Some IDEs may not expose the option graphically, but anything gcc-based should be capable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You include in `tond.cpp` in `Tondeuse.cpp`. Don't include implementation files.

If the file no longer exists (refactoring), make sure you clean the solution before building again.